# Drupal Taxonomy in D6 vs D7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm building two very big sites using Drupal. Both will have plenty of vocabularies with up to 6-7 levels deep like this:

State->District->City->Area->office name->department

The taxonomy will have multiple parents from across vocabularies.

I'm working on D6 sites and managing taxonomy hierarchy isn't easy and is bit cumbersome with D6.

**I want to know if it'd be easier with D7 especially when it comes to managing terms with multiple parents.**
Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps a clarification would help, in what way is it cumbersome, and what is the desired, not-cumbersome behavior?

Comment: Too much of scrolling for selecting terms in case of multiple parents, navigating multiple pages for long list of terms etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI for dealing with taxonomy term relationships hasn't changed much in Drupal 7 I think.

However, you might want to look into some contributed projects, for example [Taxonomy manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager), which exist for both D6 and D7. I don't know if it provides a solution for this, however.